# How to display list of all files not ending with .txt using ls command and regex?

Tags: regex

I tried,
ls (^(*.txt)).

I get error: ls cannot access. No such file or directory.

Comment: First of all... Which OS/shell do you use where `ls` is not available? IMHO `ls` does not support regexes.

Answer (score 5):

You could do:

```
ls | grep -v txt$
```

Comment: But, can't it be done without grep, using only ls and regex?\

Comment: @GaurangaRathod: I don't think it is possible without grep.

Comment: may i know what is grep @toto: i m just asking you for know about this. thanks

Comment: So, it's inability of regex to negate the expression or inability of ls to accept regex?

Comment: `ls` doesn't know about regexes, only globs (and even then, it's the shell that processes the globs, before `ls` even sees them).