# ls all directories that do NOT match multiples extensions

Tags: regex, find, pattern-matching, ls

**I am trying to list everything that does NOT end in .tar* or *.tgz**

For example

```
directory1/
ls -ltr *
06062018.tar.gz
06062018.tar.tgz
06062018.tgz
06062018/
directory2/06062018.tar.gz
directory3/06062018.tar.tgz
directory4/06062018.tgz
directory5/06062018/
directory6/06062018.1/
```

Expecting the output to be:

```
0606218/
directory5/06062018/
directory6/06062018.1/
```

**What I have researched:**

[RegEx - Find everything that does not contain a pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35181483/regex-find-everything-that-does-not-contain-a-pattern)
[List all files that do not match selector (using ls)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12634013/list-all-files-that-do-not-match-selector-using-ls)

[List files not matching a pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8525437/list-files-not-matching-a-pattern)
[How to display list of all files not ending with .txt using ls command and regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30298663/how-to-display-list-of-all-files-not-ending-with-txt-using-ls-command-and-regex)

**What I have tried:**
    ls -ltr * | grep -v $tar.gz

```
ls -ltr * !(*.tar.gz)
find ./* -maxdepth 1 ! -path "*tar.*"
find . -maxdepth 1 ! -path "[*.tar.gz|*tgz]"
ls -ltr | grep -v "[*tar*|*tgz]" 
ls -ltr */* --ignore=*.tar.gz --ignore=*tgz 
ls -ltr ./* --ignore=*.tar* --ignore=*tgz
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use two `! -name` patterns.

```
find * -maxdepth 1 ! -name '*.tar*' ! -name '*.tgz'
```